# kafka log.retention.hours inconsistency in multiple brokers

Tags: distributed-system, apache-kafka

I am trying to run multiple kafka brokers. There is a file named server.properties and there is a field "log.retention.hours" which is set to be 168 in my server.properties file. Now if i change the kafka brokers properties file and set different values of "log.retention.hours" in each properties file then how will it act in the distributed environment. I mean to say that kafka brokers in a single cluster replicates all the partitions, what will happen if the log.retention.hours in broker-1 differs with log.retention.hours in broker-2. How the replication of partitions will take place. will the data that has been deleted in server-1 will be replicated again from other brokers(assuming that (server-1 log.retention.period) < (server-2 log.retention.period)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the basic assumptions in the design of Kafka is that the brokers in a cluster will, with very few exceptions (e.g. port), have the same configuration as described [in this Kafka Improvement Proposal](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-5+-+Broker+Configuration+Management).  As a result, the scenario with inconsistent configurations that you have described in your question should be avoided.